# Update project version and versions in other projects dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven

Suppose you have 2 projects in the same Eclipse workspace. I'll call them `project1` and `project2`.

- `project1` is in 1.0.0 version;
- `project2` is in 1.2.0 version;
- `project1` has `project2` as its dependency;
- `project2` isn't a child of `project1`.

What I'm trying to achieve is:
I want to update the `project2` version to 1.3.0 (for example), and update the dependency version in `project1` to reference the new version of `project2`. Is there any automated way to do that with Maven/Eclipse or I'll have to do manually?

Comment: What you're looking for is a managed dependency.

Comment: @Zoltán I think that it's not managed dependency. What I want is to updated the version in project2 and have project1 automatically referencing this new version. project2 isn't a child of project1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no direct way with Maven. However I would try a different approach:

- `project1` writes its version number in a properties file, something like `project1.version = 1.0.0`. This can be easily done [using filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).
- `project2` reads the properties using the [properties-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) and the dependency to `project1` uses something like `<version>project1.version</version>`.

However I find this approach strange. I think that your two projects are very close and should be sharing a parent pom and have the same version, or you should handle this manually, because a version update is never trivial and should be done with caution (and testing).